# Why Child Threads do not work when using while(true) loop in main thread without sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading

When using while(true) loop in main thread with Thread.sleep() the child threads works fine but if i remove sleep method from while loop the child threads do not work. I mean, thread defines parallelism so it should work ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread th1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
          System.out.println("I love java.");
          Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
  });
 
  th1.start();
  th2.start(); // Similarly assume thread 2

  // Here's my main thread
  while(true) {
      System.out.println("I am main thread.");
      // If i use Thread.sleep(200) here, works fine but if not the child thread do not 
         print messages
  }

}
```

I am new to java, so might be the question is bit silly. Answers will be helpful.

Comment: What is your expectation ? The while loop will keep running forever in your case.

Comment: I expect that the while loop should print message. Meanwhile the threads should also work but the threads don't work until i remove sleep form while loop.

Comment: Here you can't decide which thread will be executed when. The Thread scheduler picks whichever it wants as both the threads main and th1 have the same priority 5. If you want th1 to work first you can increase it's priority. If you don't want to do that, it's the job of thread scheduler to decide what it wants to pick first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it works fine on both situations.

when you use `Thread.sleep()` in main-thread the main thread executes slower, thus you can see the "I love java" message (because t1 executes first)

when you don't use `Thread.sleep()` the main thread executes faster, so you can't see the "I love java" message. but it is there (on the first or second line of output)

debug the program to see more information. debugging shows the number of threads running currently and many more information

If you want to learn more about concurrency(multithreading) visit the link
https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrency

Comment: Yes, you are right. Instead of printing in child thread, i debug it using writing and appending in a file and the file was there with complete content. Thanks for clearing my doubt.

Comment: you don't need to write a file, only you need to do is scroll the console window up to see the message